# Conditional list Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, formatting

I am opening all the files present in zip, then converting the string to List and thereafter, breaking the list into 5 elements from each line.

**My code:**

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(dummy.zip, 'r') as mz:
    for f in mz.namelist():
        data = mz.read(f).decode('utf-8').replace("\n", '').replace("\r", ',').lstrip().rstrip().split(",") #Removing all spaces and \r from text.
        allist = [data[i:i + 5] for i in range(len(data))[::5]] #breaking list into 5 elements each
```

I am able to do it perfectly if all values are present but if any of the element in missing on particular line then it picks up the value from second line but I want to add `NA` at place of missing element.

**File data:**
*Dummy.zip = "File1 + File2"*

**File1:**

```
Yuli, yu@test.com, 0001, 8902
Su, su@test.com, 0002, 8903, Manager
```

**File:2**

```
Zaon, zn@test.com, 100, 9087, Analyst
June, ju@test.com, 278, 6078
```

**Purpose of the code:**

I am adding converting this list to dict, so adding keys to each entry as `name, email, ext, Empid, Level`

Comment: Split the file contents into lines, and then loop over the lines rather than treating the entire file as a flat list.

Comment: @barmar Thanks for suggestion, I tried doing that but got lost in the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: `with mz.open(f) as file:` then process it the same way you would process an ordinary file. You could could even make use of the `csv` module to parse it.

Comment: You can then use functions like `readline()` or `for line in file:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
texts = [b"Yuli, yu@test.com, 0001, 8902\r\nSu, su@test.com, 0002, 8903, Manager",
         b"Zaon, zn@test.com, 100, 9087, Analyst\r\nJune, ju@test.com, 278, 6078"]

result =[]
keys = "name,email,ext,Empid,Level".split(",")
# you do: 
# with zipfile.ZipFile(dummy.zip, 'r') as mz: 
#     for f in mz.namelist(): 
#         t = mz.read(f) here instead
# instead
for t in texts:
    for line in t.decode("utf-8").split("\n"):
        d = {k:"NA" for k in keys} # init all keys with NA
        # update with actual values
        d.update(zip(keys,(l.strip() for l in line.strip().split(","))))
        # add to result list
        result.append(d) 
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Yuli', 'email': 'yu@test.com', 'ext': '0001', 'Empid': '8902', 'Level': 'NA'}, 
 {'name': 'Su', 'email': 'su@test.com', 'ext': '0002', 'Empid': '8903', 'Level': 'Manager'},
 {'name': 'Zaon', 'email': 'zn@test.com', 'ext': '100', 'Empid': '9087', 'Level': 'Analyst'}, 
 {'name': 'June', 'email': 'ju@test.com', 'ext': '278', 'Empid': '6078', 'Level': 'NA'}]
```